# Edge labeling of Complete Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I have the following code

```
rand = {1, 2, 3};
el = EdgeList[CompleteGraph[5]]
g = CompleteGraph[5, 
  EdgeLabels -> Table[el[[i]] -> RandomChoice[rand], {i, Length[el]}]]
```

What I want is to get the labels of each edge of my graph in a list. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The thing is I want to input two vertices and get the label of the edge between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PropertyValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyValue.html) (and/or [`AnnotationValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnnotationValue.html) in versions 12.1+) as follows:

```
ClearAll[edgeLabel]
edgeLabel[g_, {a_, b_}] := PropertyValue[{g, UndirectedEdge[a, b]}, EdgeLabels]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[7];
cg = CompleteGraph[5,
  EdgeLabels -> {_ :> RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}]}, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Transpose[{Defer /@ Unevaluated @ #, #} & @
   Unevaluated @ {edgeLabel[cg, {1, 5}], edgeLabel[cg, {5, 1}], 
     edgeLabel[cg, {5, 3}], edgeLabel[cg, {3, 5}], 
     edgeLabel[cg, {2, 6}], edgeLabel[cg, {2, 2}]}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1234];

rand = {1, 2, 3};
el = EdgeList[CompleteGraph[5]];
g = CompleteGraph[5,
  VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> Table[el[[i]] -> RandomChoice[rand], {i, Length[el]}]]
```

[image]

```
label[graph_, edges_] := First@Cases[Options[g, EdgeLabels],
   Rule[UndirectedEdge @@ Sort[edges],
     lbl_] :> lbl, Infinity]

label[g, {1, 4}]

(* 1 *)

label[g, {5, 3}]

(* 3 *)
```